# Element equals its index code wars problem need to pass time limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

```
def index_equals_value(arr):
    for num in range(len(arr)):
        if abs(arr[num]) == num:
            return arr[num]
    return -1
```

The time limit is 1.500 seconds but my code is 1684.96 ms. what can I do to make it faster? I am a beginner at python and would like some advice. anything is helpful!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. What have you already tried? Why do you use `abs`? Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: I got kind of confused and I thought needed it but realize I didn't thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` to eliminate some function calls and lookups.

```
for num, x in enumerate(arr)
```

Is `abs` really needed? If not, remove it.

Comment: I removed abs and put in enumerate but it is still not fast enough any more ideas?

Comment: @austinvan295 How are you using `enumerate`?

Comment: @austinvan295 I mean are you using `x` or are you still doing a lookup?

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean I replaced my whole for num in range(arr)) with the for num, x in enumerate(arr) and that was it. It works but still not fast enough.

Comment: Use `x` in place of `arr[num]`. That'll eliminate two lookups. For reference see the docs: [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: Dang it still says the same thing. Exceeded time limit of 1.500 seconds
Completed in 1682.28ms very weird might be the question tho but everything works great and yeah I need to learn that line for the for loop makes my code look cleaner

Comment: I am guessing it wants me to do a list comprehension without a loop